# Error on installation 2sic_2SexyContent_10.25.02_Install.zip

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

While installing 2sic_2SexyContent_10.25.02_Install.zip into DNN getting error. Error screenshot : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY5Dx.png)

My DNN version Evoq: 09.02.01 (199). Pleaes let me know if I am missing anything

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

pote, welcome to Stack Overflow

Your question is much to vague for anybody to help you with it. Basically there is nothing there that anybody could help. I suggest you try either some other versions of 2sxc or other versions of evoq, and probably also check in the Admin-Logs to see more detailed errors.

My best guess BTW is that you have a currupt zip file - so maybe you just need to download it again from github.